# Fixed Div Stops The Entire Page From Scrolling

Tags: html

I am trying to create a website with a fixed div in the background to act as a backdrop for the content against the background. When I set it to `position:fixed` in the CSS the page will no longer scroll, and any other way seems to break the page. Any suggestions?

(The div I'm speaking about it the top one with the bg-container class).

Index.php:
(The `<p>` tag was for me to test the scrolling of the page.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<!-- 00a7fe -->
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Sublimity Gaming</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        <div id="logo-pos" style="height:100%;padding-bottom:100px">
          <a class="logo-sublimity" href="index.php" style="top:25px; left:60px"></a>
          <a class="logo-gaming" href="index.php" style="top:25px; right:60px"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="nav-pos">
          <p style="color:white; padding:100px">Point1<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Point2<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Point3<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Point4<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Point5</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And my main.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto Lt";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
* {
    padding:0;margin:0
}
html, body {
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    overflow:auto
}
body {
    background-image:url('imgs/bg1.jpg'); background-color:black;
    background-position:top left; font-family:"Roboto Lt";
    font-size:14px; width:100%; position:fixed;
}
.main {
    background:transparent no-repeat top center;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%; padding-top:180px; padding-bottom: 24px;
}
.bg-container {
    background:url('imgs/container-bg.png') transparent top center fixed;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    width:1025px; height:100%;
    left:50%; margin-left:-512.5px;
    display:inline-block; position:fixed
}
.header {
    background:transparent no-repeat top center;
    margin:auto; height:180px; width:100%;
    position:absolute; margin-top:-180px
}
.logo-sublimity {
    background:url('imgs/logo-sublimity.png') no-repeat;
    width:447px;height:129px;
    position:absolute; display:block
}
.logo-gaming {
    background:url('imgs/logo-gaming.png') no-repeat;
    width:379px; height:129px;
    position:absolute; display:block
}
.nav-bar-container {
    /*TODO*/
}
```

Comment: why don't you just set background-attachment:fixed instead of using a fixed div? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have all of your content inside of the `.bg-container` div so when you set it to fixed position with a full screen width you're eliminating the scrolling ability. Easy fix:

```
<body>
  <div class="bg-container"> </div>

  <div class="main">
     [ ... ]
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Thought I had tried that but it seems not, all fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `backstretch` jquery. `Backstretch` is a jQuery plugin that allows you to add a dynamically-resized background image to any page. The image will stretch to fit the page, and will automatically resize as the window size changes.

Here is an example:

> http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/